# Laravel Error when referencing a resource in a resource

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using a Laravel Json Resource in my controller, as follows

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $itemsWithTranslations = MenuItem::where(['menu_id' => $request->id, 'parent_id' => null])
        ->with(['children', 'translations'])
        ->orderBy('sort_order', 'asc')
        ->get();

    return MenuItemResource::collection($itemsWithTranslations);
}
```

Now I would like to generate a collection, inside this collection with the children for the item that's being shown.

The following code works fine. **Notice how I commented out the children reference**

```
class MenuItemResource extends JsonResource
{

    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'text' => $this->title,
            // 'children' => MenuItemResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('children')),
            'data' => [
                'id' => [
                    'value' => $this->id,
                    'type' => 'hidden'
                ],
                'title' => [
                    'value' => $this->title,
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => 'Title'
                ],
                'resource_link' => [
                    'value' => $this->resource_link,
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => 'Resource Link'
                ],
                'translations' => MenuItemTranslationResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('translations'))->keyBy(function ($translation) {
                    return $translation['locale'];
                })
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

When I uncomment the children, I get the following error

> "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\AnonymousResourceCollection::keyBy()"

Is it wrong, to include a Resource inside a resource? Or how should I go about this?

#### Model

```
class MenuItem extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'menu_items';
    protected $fillable = ['menu_id', 'parent_id', 'title', 'order', 'resource_link', 'html_class', 'is_blank'];

    public function translations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(MenuItemTranslation::class, 'menu_item_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(MenuItem::class, 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

#### Extra Information

When I return the following data, it does return empty as a collection for the children.

```
MenuItemResource::collection($this->children);
```

This returns

[image]

While if I return the children without a collection, it returns them (for 1 item, which is correct)

```
return $this->children;
```

returns

[image]

Comment: no, we can use resource inside other resource.

Comment: can you show your model relation to "children" in "MenuItem" model

Comment: added to the question, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

you should use ChildrenResource::collection

```
'children' => ChildrenResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('children'))
```

hope this works.

create a ChildrenResource class if not exists.

Comment: It's a self referencing table, as you see in the model, so it's basically the same layout. I added some more information to the question as well